# command-not-found. Can I turn off verbose error reports?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, ubuntu-12.04

I installed ubuntu server 12.04 on a linode server. Every time i execute some command not found, it raise a error like this:

```
Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+filebug
Please include the following information with the report:

command-not-found version: 0.2.44
```

I tried to search for answers but didn't find a solution. It's there any method to remove this verbose error reports?

Comment: Are all packages at their current version? `command-not-found` is a application that suggests the correct command to run or package to install when you have a typo in your command line or try to execute an application that is not installed.

Comment: Yes, all packages are at their current version.

Comment: Based on your comment below, it seems that you actually want `command-not-found` to suggest packages for you, and you do not want it to crash, but you don't want to remove it (since then it won't be able to suggest packages). If this is true, you may wish to edit your question. Reference: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912)

Answer (score 5):

See [HOW TO DISABLE COMMAND-NOT-FOUND IN UBUNTU](http://techthrob.com/2010/06/04/how-to-disable-command-not-found-in-ubuntu/);

either add the following line to your ~/.bashrc:

```
unset command_not_found_handle
```

or remove it by:

```
sudo apt-get remove command-not-found command-not-found-data
```

Comment: It works. But when i type a command which is not installed on the machine, Ubuntu should suggest me install related packages. But it's not.

Comment: @Ikbear you can try to reinstall the packages using `sudo apt-get install command-not-found command-not-found-data` after removing them.

Comment: The 'unset command_not_found_handle' option is the way to go here, IMHO. Thank you for this. It was really frustrating to make a typo and then have to wait for it to try and look up a package.